# In teamcity, can an artifact be executed in a build step?

Tags: teamcity

For example, project A generates two artifacts `processor.exe` and `t.txt`. Then in project B, can I add a build step to execute `processor.exe t.txt`?

I know there are two Runner types(*.NET Process Runner* and *Command Line*) that can execute programs. But how to get the paths of these artifacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think it should be possible to run with Command Line runner *.exe file generated by other build.

You just have to make sure that build agent which runs Project A outputs these artifacts to place where build agent which runs Project B has access (in case if you have single agent it's not a concern obviously). And probably placing these artifacts into agent's working directory is not the best place because it can be cleared by doing clean checkout from VCS. Just choose some generic directory on the server and specify it for artifact output in Project A and then for Command Line runner in Project B.

Comment: So that's the regular practice.. Thanks!